# javascript/jquery global variables not being assigned

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to be able to dynamically reload the variable I'm going to be using for an auto complete field, but I'm having trouble loading the initial call. Presently, my javascript consists of this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myList;

  function setTextSuggest() {
    $("#loginInput").autocomplete({
      source: myList,
      appendTo: "#loginDiv"
    });
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('StarWars.php', function(data) {
      myList = JSON.parse(data);
      //alert(myList); //DOES NOTHING WHEN UNCOMMENTED!!!!
      setTextSuggest();
    });
  });
</script>
```

When I replace myList in the alert with 'data["info"]', it spits out the JSON info I'm expecting. However, if I were to uncomment the alert and run it on myList, nothing at all would print. myList is supposed to have global scope here, but I can't figure out why it's not assigning inside my readied function.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

EDIT:

The following is the object being returned from StarWars.php (created via json_encode):

```
{"UserList":["Han Solo","Leia Organa","Luke Skywalker","Darth Vader","Emperor Palpatine","Chewbacca","R2-D2","C-3PO","Lando Calrissian","Lobot","Yoda","Obi-Wan Kenobi","Uncle Owen","Aunt Beru","Wedge Antilles","Boba Fett"]}
```

If I set the getJSON request as:

```
$.getJSON('StarWars.php', function(data) {
    myList = data.UserList;
    alert(myList);
    setTextSuggest();
});
```

Then it shows me the list of names, but I still have nothing set in my autocomplete.

Edit 2:

I have accepted Jack's answer for this question. While my code does still have issues (autocomplete is not appending yet), Jack's solution has moved it out of the realm of a question on global variables and JSON data retrieval and into a question about using the jQuery 1.8 autocomplete correctly. I feel this is a different question, so I'm marking this issue as complete. -D.G.

Comment: The problem will more then likely lie in the scope of myList. Put the setTextSuggest and var myList inside of the document.ready and it should work.

Comment: I disagree.  once this callback gets hit, myList is reassigned to `JSON.parse(data)`, so it doesn't matter what's happened to it before.  Unless `myList` is getting changed asynchronously in multiple locations, this should not be a scope issue.  My suggestion is to but a `debugger` statement before the JSON.parse line and see what data is before it is parsed, and then what myList is after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from your question, `data` is already a proper array / object (not text), so you don't need `JSON.parse()` at all.

Just this should do:

```
myList = data;
```

Comment: You are correct that myList begins to accept information when edited that way, but it still isn't parsed correctly to be used as a javascript array. Thank you for pointing that out, though.

Comment: @D.G. that's a different problem; which autocomplete library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The matter of global or local scope is not the issue here.  Your alert should still fire and display `[object Object]` because you aren't referencing any properties of the object declared with `data`.

I have created the following jsFiddle as reference: http://jsfiddle.net/u8rVj/.  You will see that the observations stated above do occur.

What is the JSON output?